# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

what is wrong with this Code

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ChangeRevision] (@oldRev tinyint)
RETURNS varchar(1) 
AS
begin

declare @newRev varchar(1)
DECLARE @newval int
set @newval=CAST (@oldRev as int)

case @newval
begin
when 0 then set @newRev='Z'
when 1 then set @newRev='A'
when 2 then set @newRev='B'
when 3 then set @newRev='C'

end
return @newRev;

END
```

i have following error
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Return'.

Comment: `CASE` is an expression operator in SQL.  It is *NOT* a statement and cannot be used like one.  `IF` on the other hand is a statement, and probably what you want here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work:

```
SET @newRev = (SELECT case @newval
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Z'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'C'
    END)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is not `BEGIN` keyword for `case` in **tsql**

```
select @newRev=case @newval
when 0 then 'Z'
when 1 then 'A'
when 2 then 'B'
when 3 then 'C'
end
```

Comment: You cannot have **code** (`set @newRev='Z'`) in a T-SQL `CASE` statement - the `when...then...` can only **return** values - not execute code.

Comment: Still not OK - you need to use `when 0 then 'Z' when 1 then 'A'` - also **no assignment** inside the `when..then..`

Answer (score 1):

`case` doesn't need a `begin`, but does need an `end`

e.g.

```
SET @newRev = (SELECT case @newval
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Z'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'C'
    END)
```

[MSDN CASE Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)